# How do I save and read an integer on android libgdx?

Tags: android, file, integer, save, libgdx

How do I save an integer that can be overwritten and then read it on android? I am using libgdx. I know how to do it for my desktop, but I want internal storage.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use libgdx **[Preferences](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences)**.

That way it will work cross-plattform! (including Android)

Since you just want to store some Integer that should be just what you need.

See example:

```
//get a preferences instance
Preferences prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("My Preferences");

//put some Integer
prefs.putInteger("score", 99);

//persist preferences
prefs.flush();

//get Integer from preferences, 0 is the default value.
prefs.getInteger("score", 0);
```

Comment: This works, but when I close out of the app and end the task, it doesn't save the highscore and goes back to 0.

Comment: make sure that you `flush()` before closing the app.

Comment: ok so just have it flush() everytime? I have it in an if statement and that is not called every run

Comment: You could use [libgdx life-cycle methods](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/The-life-cycle) to persist your preferences. So for example you could do `prefs.flush()` in the `pause()` method.

Comment: `prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences(file);
prefs.putInteger("score", score);
prefs.flush();
highscore = prefs.getInteger("score", 0);` Yet it still won't save after the app is closed completely. It will save, though, if you keep the app open.

Comment: When you get it you need to save it to an integer like this: int score = prefs.getInteger("score", 0);     Also, when I would save it as highscore, I noticed it was saving it as highScore.  So, if you save it as highscore, then save it as highScore and retrieve it as highScore.

Answer (score 3):

There are different ways to do that:

1. You can write to a `FileHandle`. Just create a `FileHandle` like `Gdx.files.local("myfile.txt");` and write to it using `fileHandle.writeString(Integer.toString(myInt));`
   Note, that `Internal` and `Classpath` are read-only, so you can't write files there.
   Also note, that not all types of the `gdx.files.` are usable for all backends. More on that [here](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/FileHandling#File_%28Storage%29_Types).
2. The second way to do that are the [Preferences](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Preferences.html). The `Preferences` are the only way to have persistent data for HTML5 applications.
   The `Preferences` are XML files in which you can store, read and change data.
   To create `Preferences` for your app you just need to call:

   Preferences myPref = Gdx.app.getPreferences("PreferenceName");

Note, that you should use the full name, for example `com.stackoverflow.preferences`, as on desktop all `Preferences` use the same file.
To write data you can use `myPref.putInteger("name", value)` for `Integer`s, `myPref.putBoolean(("name", value)` for `Boolean`s... Make sure you call `myPref.flush()` after all changes, to save the new data.
To get the data you can call `myPref.getInteger("name, defaultValue")`. The default value is returned if there is no data with the given name.
More on `Preferences` [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences).

Hope i could help.