# Exporting of Android project - how to add a folder to .apk which will be installed too

Tags: android, sdk, libgdx, export, apk

(I am writing in Java and using libGDX as a framework, and i am using Eclipse)
So, i am using a images which are in assets folder, which probably does not exists, because if i export project as a .jar it does not create an assets folder, but the images are loaded in game, which is good(the .jar file probably includes a assets folder). but, this is my problem, i am creating a highscore saving, so, if i am trying to create a file: Highscore.bin to assets(game is exported and running)  it does not save to there, so the highscore is not saved anywhere, so saving does not work. I tried to export it to .jar and created a folder to where it is creating a file and updating a file(C://pc//folder//highscore.bin. and i set the destination of saving highscore to : C://pc//folder//highscore.bin and it works! But on android, i actually cant add a folder to a mobile for every mobile individually. So my question is, how to create an .apk file(which installs you a game) that it will install a game, and that folder? If i am exporting it to .apk there is not a function which lets me to do this.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I've no idea what bicycle are you trying to invent here, but Android has its own ways to store your app's data. Basically you have few options: database, shared preferences, and private folder for your application (you can get a handle to the last one by calling getExternalFilesDir() function). So call this function and store whatever you want into that directory. More info at: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: You should definitely use Preferences to store your highscores. LibGDX has a Preferences class that can be used cross-plattform. See my related answer with a simple example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22772354/2399024

Comment: Oh, Thank you ;)) :D That preferences are working. And it is a lot of easier to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create any files in APK. APK and JAR are just archives and contain different information including classes and assets (You can try to open any jar or apk with any file archiver like WinZip). Most games are using device file system to store game resources and save files. Some code:

```
//Read
FileHandle file = Gdx.files.internal("savefile/highscore.txt");
if(file.exists()){
  highscore = Float.valueOf(file.readString());
}
//Write
if(currentscore > highscore){
   file.writeString(Float.toString(currentscore ),false);
}
```

But in most cases Preferences are better suited to store small numbers or strings in memory. Nice tutorial here: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences